# Python 2.7 - Redirect handler isn't passing parameters on re-direct

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I have a url that I am hitting on a site that can be moved, and when the endpoint is moved, I need the POST/GET parameters to be reapplied.  What am I missing to ensure this handler does this?

```
class RedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):


  def http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301(
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
        result.status = code
        return result

    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
        result.status = code
        return result
```

When I watch the traffic through fiddler, I notice that the token, which is used for authentication gets dropped.

**(please note I cannot use requests for this solution, it must be standard library only)**

Thank you

Comment: Where your Cookies ? (or your session information)

Comment: @SDilmac so you think a cookie handler will solve this problem?

Comment: True ! All  web services using cookie cos can't save all actions of visitor.

Comment: @SDilmac I added a cookiejar and handler to the opener, and no cookie was returned from the response server, so my guess is that the server will not return a cookie.  I even tried doing the same thing (watching the traffic in fiddler) in a web browser and no authentication was returned.  My guess is that the webbrowser persists the form parameters from url to url.  I need to somehow on the 302 redirect capture the params/data from the original request, then push them to the new request.  I tried creating a new request object, but that throws an error.

Comment: Try this https://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/source/browse/trunk/PythonProxy.py . Browsers, servers, clients, ssl, and a lot more..  You want grab some header on a packet but if touch it will be corrupted. Need clone first for reuse. Or set your computer as gateway ! i hope help.

Comment: @SDilmac so you are saying when downloading, I should create a local proxy and then go through that proxy?

Comment: Yes,  if you use non transparent proxy on outside. You can't grab request headers !

Comment: Try: https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/2077115

Comment: @josh1234, obviously you've said you can't use requests, but can I ask why? Would it be possible to vendorize requests?

Answer (score 2):

The story about HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 status codes 302, 303 and 307 is a little complicated. Basically you see the expected and [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request) behaviour (you may also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077586/2072035) for longer description):

> The default implementation of this method does not strictly follow [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html), which says that 301 and 302 responses to `POST` requests must not be automatically redirected without confirmation by the user. In reality, browsers do allow automatic redirection of these responses, changing the `POST` to a `GET`, and the default implementation reproduces this behavior.

And you go the right way, but override the wrong methods. Here's the source of `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request`:

```
def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl):
    """Return a Request or None in response to a redirect.
    ...
    Return None if you can't but another Handler might.
    """
    m = req.get_method()
    if (code in (301, 302, 303, 307) and m in ("GET", "HEAD")
        or code in (301, 302, 303) and m == "POST"):
        # ...
        newurl = newurl.replace(' ', '%20')
        newheaders = dict((k,v) for k,v in req.headers.items()
                          if k.lower() not in ("content-length", "content-type")
                         )
        return Request(newurl,
                       headers=newheaders,
                       origin_req_host=req.get_origin_req_host(),
                       unverifiable=True)
    else:
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)
```

Several observations here. It doesn't pass `data`, thus new request is `GET`. It filters out `content-length` and `content-type` headers, which are required for a correct `POST`. If fact, in my example `req.headers` is an empty dict, so I resorted to `req.header_items()` (see `unredirected_hdrs`). Moreover is doesn't handle `POST` and 307 redirect.

Here's a correct redirector handler implementation for POST and 302 redirect. Here's also complete CherryPy simulation (do `pip install cherrypy` before).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import urllib2
from urllib2 import HTTPRedirectHandler, Request

import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


class RedirectHandler(HTTPRedirectHandler):

    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl):
      if code == 302 and req.get_method() == 'POST':
        return Request(newurl, headers=dict(req.header_items()), data=req.data,
          origin_req_host=req.get_origin_req_host(), unverifiable=True)
      else:
        return HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, 
          headers, newurl)


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(RedirectHandler())
    return opener.open('http://localhost:8080/redirect', data='foo=bar')

  @cherrypy.expose
  def redirect(self, **kwargs):
    print('Before redirect {0}'.format(kwargs))
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/target', 302)
  
  @cherrypy.expose
  def target(self, **kwargs):
    return 'Target received {0} {1}'.format(cherrypy.request.method, kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will test this and get back to you!