# IIS redirect with cache response header

Tags: redirect, caching, iis, web-config

I am trying to develop a "semi-permanent" redirect in IIS 8.5 using a 301 response along with cache expiration header(s), perhaps a max-age or cache-control with a reasonable expiration.  However IIS's URL Rewrite [doesn't seem to support](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) adding response headers to a redirect rule.  I see how to affect the cache at a larger scope, [like this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/manually-override-cache-control-directives-using-application-request-routing), but not how to apply them to individual redirects.  I.e.:

```
<rule name="foo" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="foo" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="/foo($|\/$)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/full_url_for_now" redirectType="Permanent" someParameterThatLetsMeSetResponseHeaders="max-age:3600"/>
</rule>
```

Thanks for any advice.  I'm guessing there's some other way to do this for individual rules/paths/etc., but no luck finding it.  If it's not possible, then I'll have to set the cache parameters at a higher level.

Why: the redirect is for a vanity URL; the path will be the same for a month or two but may change after that.  Straight 301 will [cache permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s) in some browsers.  302/307 will cause the the vanity URL to be [indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467664/do-i-need-to-use-http-redirect-code-302-or-307), which would mess up my SEO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cache response header goes in outbound rules:

```
    <outboundRules>
          <rule name="Require clients to revalidationpermanent redirects">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache_Control" pattern=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="301" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="public, must-revalidate, max-age=0"/>
            </rule>

    </outboundRules>
```

**Result:**

Fiddler Screenshot:

[image]

This will help you avoid the horror that cannot be undone with [301 permanent redirects](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/). I encourage you to read this excellent article.

With credit to
http://www.gillsoft.ie/using-url-rewrite-to-improve-your-site-performance-001

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Many comments on these articles suggest using 302s instead, which hurts SEO.  This solution seems like the right compromise.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the similar issue so I tried this solution. I put this configuration under <rewrite> tag but it did not work. I don't have dot (.) in mu URLs to I just kept asterisk(*) in pattern, kept it blank but nothing worked. Can you please help

Comment: @Imad I have no idea why it wouldn't work.